# Gravatar : Is there a default image?

Tags: image, default, gravatar

I have implemented gravatar for a portal I am building and wanted to know if there is a default image URL for gravatar? Not all people who visit the site are logged in or have email addresses, in such a case, is there a default image that can be shown (accessible via gravatar url)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To select a default image, you can use the `d` parameter:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b3be63a4c2a439b013787725dfce802?d=identicon
```

Or without a hash:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=identicon
```

Or without the `d` parameter:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar
```

Source: [gravatar.com](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/url).

Comment: Normally this would be my suggestion as well. However, it does not cater for his requirement for where some users are not registered & do not *have* an email address (which therefore cannot be hashed and sent along to Gravatar).

Comment: Hmm, strange. According to the Gravatar instructions you linked to, the hash is required (not optional). I wonder if it working is by design or coincidence. However if it works, its certainly another option. :)

Comment: lol... And I just realized it also work without anything... : )

Answer (score 34):

Gravatar describe the options for default images here: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

You can select which option you want by adding the appropriate name/value pair to your url. For example, you could use "mystery person" (d=mp) which looks like this:

[image]

The above image was created with the url `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mp`. Note that the email hash string has been omitted but normally you would include it as part of the request.

Options listed at the above link:

> - 404: do not load any image if none is associated with the email hash, instead return an HTTP 404 (File Not Found) response
> - mp: (mystery-person) a simple, cartoon-style silhouetted outline of a person (does not vary by email hash)
> - identicon: a geometric pattern based on an email hash
> - monsterid: a generated 'monster' with different colors, faces, etc
> - wavatar: generated faces with differing features and backgrounds
> - retro: awesome generated, 8-bit arcade-style pixelated faces
> - robohash: a generated robot with different colors, faces, etc
> - blank: a transparent PNG image (border added to HTML below for demonstration purposes)

As you would hope, using the size option `s=<pixels>` also changes the size of the default image.

[image]

The above image was created with `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=retro&s=32`

Thanks to [@Alireza Rezaee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11455069/alireza-rezaee) for the updated image types.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a custom URL for the default/fallback avatar. However, the custom URL must point to a publicly available image or else it wont show. You can [learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763944/gravatar-setting-custom-default-avatar-avatar-not-shown) and at [gravatar.com](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/).

Here is a PHP function I use to when working with gravatar images.

```
function myprefix_get_gravatar_url( $email, $default='mm', $size=92 )
{
    $email = md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
    $default = urlencode( $default );
    $size = (int)$size;

    $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
    if ( is_ssl() )
        $url = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/';

    return $url.$email."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$img2x = myprefix_get_gravatar_url( 
    'spacepants@goofygoof.it',
    'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
    184
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really, no. That is missing the point of the Gravatar service. It is designed so that your users can register their email address(es) and associate a gravatar image with it/them. Your site (and other sites) can then query Gravatar to give back the image which is associated with the email address in question.

If you want an image showing for users who do not even enter an email address on your website, you have two solutions that I can see:

1. Do it in your own code. When you are dealing with a user who has no email address, you can just output a default image of your own choosing. Of course, this means it will not be done using a gravatar address and it'll be something you'll need to be serving yourself.
2. Register an email address yourself dedicated to users who do not have/enter their own. For example, you could register something like `default-gravatar@myapp.example.com` and then register this with the Gravatar service and associate your chosen default image with this. Your own app code will still need to output the appropriate gravatar URL substituting this email address in place of the user's non-existant one when constructing the image URL, but it will allow you to use a gravatar URL which is something you have asked for.

Comment: Your #2 answer can make it really easy to change the default gravitar. Most websites need at least one email address anyway so this is a great idea

Answer (score 2):

For those who just want a link to a given email's image (this does not address the OP's request, but this page is prominent in web searches): From almost any POSIX shell you can generate the 256 pixel gravatar URL for "somebody@example.com" with:

```
echo "http://gravatar.com/avatar/$(echo -n somebody@example.com | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')?s=256"
```

You do need to think enough to replace somebody@example.com with the email in question. I included the "?s=256" to show how to specify the size.

I needed this to illustrate to somebody what a gravatar is.