# What is a good gravatar example email?

Tags: demo, gravatar

I just made a demo after seeing a similar one in the Ember.js documentation that gets your gravatar based on your email. I’m currently using tomster@emberjs.com as the default but that seems wrong as it’s a React app. Does anybody know of a good default to use?

Comment: You could, you know, make one.

Comment: @David Well yes, but I’m wondering if there is a standard or something like that

Comment: 1) Gravatar is a commercial service, not a standard.  2) Because it is naive ... and you have already been given the only practical answer.

Comment: You guys don’t get it. I’ll edit my question to be more clear

Comment: @StephenC I mean a good default email that has a Gravatar associated with it. What would you use?

Comment: I would invent an email address, and register a Gravatar for it.  But people have already told you that.

Comment: It might be more clear if you explain why you need to have a default? Just so that when you show your demo you have something to show or what?

Comment: @StephenC I edited my post to make it better. Could you undo your down vote? I can’t post a new question now :\

Comment: @Hum4n01d: See what above?  A still-off-topic question that was answered in the first comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: @David What can I do to make the question better? (It’s my first question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a disposable email account and create a WordPress account with it and add an image (e.g. from uifaces.com).

That's what I did with **jitewaboh@lagify.com**, which you are free to use. The email md5 is 09abd59eb5653a7183ba812b8261f48b, so the avatar url is https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/09abd59eb5653a7183ba812b8261f48b

[image: Fake avatar]

Comment: Coming back to this, this is exactly what I would do today

Answer (score 2):

> What is a good gravatar example email?

AFAIK, there isn't one.

The best idea is to invent a fictitious email address and register a Gravatar for it.   Or "fake" it in your application, demo, whatever.  Or use your own.  Or if the above are all problematic, abandon the idea of an example Gravatar entirely.

If you use an existing identity with an associated Gravatar you are liable to get into trouble:

- You might offend the real owner of the identity.  (Watch out for lawyer letters!)
- The real owner might decide to break their gravatar.
- The real owner might decide to embarrass >>you<< by placing an offensive image as their Gravatar.
- The identity / email might be surrendered or hacked and the new owner might do one of the above.

---

And there isn't a "standard or something" that applies to Gravatars

Answer (score 2):

You can use test1@example.com, test2@example.com & test3@example.com

E.g., https://gravatar.com/avatar/aa99b351245441b8ca95d54a52d2998c for test1

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536965/1623178 for url crafting)

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, here is a gravatar email generator solving this exact problem!

https://vinicius73.github.io/gravatar-url-generator/

Comment: This only shows default avatars for a few services, but not real avatars set on actual accounts (mock or not) on those services.