# Gravatar Image not displaying correctly on ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, avatar, gravatar

I have a website developed by using asp.net , c#

In there I made my own comment system. If user want to post a comment He has to enter comment, Name and email.

[image]

When I load the comments I am using this code to load the gravator.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

/// Hashes an email with MD5.  Suitable for use with Gravatar profile
/// image urls
public static string HashEmailForGravatar(string email)
{
    // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.  
    MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.  
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(email));

    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes  
    // and create a string.  
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.  
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();  // Return the hexadecimal string. 
}
```

Then using this code to assign it

```
//  Compute the hash
string hash = HashEmailForGravatar(email);

//  Assemble the url and return
return string.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}", hash);
```

But all I am getting is this default blue image.
[image]

Here I am explaining the assining part
This is the element on ASPX page

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("GravatorURL")%>' />
```

This is where I am assiging value to that Eval part

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = objBlog_BLL.GetArticleComment(articleID);
                dt.Columns.Add("GravatorURL", typeof(String));
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string CommenterEmail = dr["author_email"].ToString();
                    string hash = HashEmailForGravatar(CommenterEmail);

                    string myGravatar = string.Format("//www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?size=50", hash);
                    dr["GravatorURL"] = myGravatar;
                }
                dListComment.DataSource = dt;
                dListComment.DataBind();
```

THis is the HTML tag rendering on client side

```
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/4F3FFEF1297E4BF2F746007DFCD36FA5?size=50">
```

> I lowered this result by using .LoverCase() . but still the result is
>   same.

But this email address has an image. I found an another site called [Avatarapi.com](https://www.avatarapi.com/). In there you can enter the email address and check the image. It is fully working. THey also provide a API to do this. All you have to do is
using this code

```
<script src="https://www.avatarapi.com/js.aspx?email=your_email@gmail.com&size=128">
</script>
```

But problem is they are pointing the URL back to their site when you hover on the gravator. So I need a clean method. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you looked at the `href` of your image to see if it's actually being inserted into the HTML the way you think it is?

Comment: Yes I checked it

Comment: what image control are you using? curious because it looks like the http is getting stripped off, but it isn't in my test. i'm using `<asp:Image ID="imgGravatar" runat="server" />` and `imgGravatar.ImageUrl = string.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}", hash);`. Fwiw, i did strip the protocol (http) from the url, inside the browser, and it still worked so it might not matter at all, but it's odd.

Comment: @wazz I am using this    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("GravatorURL")%>' />

Comment: Update the question with that aspx markup and show exactly how/when you're assigning the url. Explain the Eval part too. the plot thickens.

Comment: @wazz updated the question. Please check

Comment: try adding http to see what happens. something strange is going on with your own email address, what about others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine for producing my gravatar if it's applied to an all-lowercase email address. There are just a few things I'd check:

1. Gravatar's [docs](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) show the initial email address needing to be trimmed and converted to lowercase prior to hashing. Try passing `email.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()` to the GetBytes method in the first place.
2. You haven't shown the actual string produced by your `string.Format()`. It's possible (though unlikely) that your culture settings could be affecting how the string is represented. You could pass a `CultureInfo.Invariant` argument to `string.Format()`, or just switch to concatenating the strings directly with the `+` operator.
3. You haven't shown the actual HTML tag that gets rendered in your browser. There's a possibility that something client-side is not reading or applying the server's response correctly.

#### Update

According to https://www.avatarapi.com/:

> This API uses public profile information provided by Google, via a publicly exposed Google data source to determine the name and profile image of the user. There are over 1 billion profile pics available via this API. The API works best with gmail addresses, but many other email accounts are registered with Google.

So you're asking about producing a Gravatar image, but you think you're not getting a valid result because you're comparing your results against a service that uses Google Profile images, and only falls back on gravatar as a backup option.

Comment: Please check the question. Here is the HTML element <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/4F3FFEF1297E4BF2F746007DFCD36FA5?size=50">

Comment: +1 : I tried capitalizing a letter in the email address and i got the gravatar logo returned instead of a valid image.

Comment: @Sylar: Thanks for adding that information to the question. I'm going to assert that there is *no way* that the code you posted produced the avatar URL you ended up with. For one thing, your code uses a format string of "x2", which would produce a lower-case hash, whereas the URL you provided is all in upper-case. Besides that, your string.Format call includes "http://" at the front, but your url starts with "//". Unless you post [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's extremely difficult for anyone else to help you find your bug.

Comment: @Sylar: Just as an example, your code produces http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0cf15665a9146ba852bf042b0652780a when given the email address tomster@emberjs.com (pulled from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41786225/120955)).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior updated the question. Please check

Comment: that email does not work for me. maybe Avatarapi.com is caching old info, or supplying fake images when there is no image. is that image actually klprageeth? or one he supplied?

Comment: @Sylar: See my update. avatarapi pulls from Google Profile pics, so they'll have images for email addresses that don't have gravatar accounts.